# Deep Linking: Refresh leads to crash

Tags: angular, apache, dart, deep-linking, angular-dart

I have developed a angular-dart app and deployed it to domain.tld/subdirectory/ on my apache2 server.

I have created a .htaccess file and configured the index.html with a base href="/subdirectory/".

Everything works fine if I load the root or one more level (domain.tld/subdirectory/home). I can reach the deep linking pages (domain.tld/subdirectory/action/3) as well, but if I refresh the page I will receive the blank index.html screen. If I open the console in Firefox it tells me that the page tries to open:
 GET https://domain.tld/subdirectory/action/main.dart.js
which of course cannot work.

The main.dart.js is located in domain.tld/subdirectory/ but the client thinks it is in the action-subdirectory. What is wrong?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /subdirectory/
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
    <script defer src="main.dart.js">
    <base href="/subdirectory/">
  </head>
  <body onload="">
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```